# Retrieving data from Swift to PHP then back to Swift

Tags: php, swift

In my PHP file, I have this code:

```
$user_id = $_POST['user_id']; 
require_once('Connect.php'); 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Loans WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
```

I check it in HTML and it works. Nothing's wrong with it. However, when I try to put it in Swift, I have a problem with that. I don't how will I put value of "user_id" from Swift file to PHP file then go back to Swift to execute the PHP file.

Here's my Swift code:

```
if let loanArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "loans")  as? NSArray
                        {
                            for loans in loanArray
                            {
                                if let loanDict = loans as? NSDictionary
                                {
                                    if let name = loanDict.value(forKey: getBnum)
                                    {
                                        self.borrNoArray.append(name as! String)
                                    }

                                    if let name = loanDict.value(forKey: "loan_no")
                                    {
                                        self.loanNoArray.append(name as! String)
                                    }

                                    if let name = loanDict.value(forKey: "amount")
                                    {
                                        self.loanAmtArray.append(name as! String)
                                    }

                                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                                    })
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

I already tried this Swift code and it also works. I have a default value for "user_id", it is 0 and I just add some info about it just for me to see if my Swift code works and it is.

Comment: This looks like a second duplicate of your original question, Jan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swift 3.1**

**In PHP**

By your requirement there are different options available. As well as above code the same way on `connect.php`. But you need to write `SELECT` query to `INSERT` query for send `parameters` through mobile end and Also you need one more reference variable to get whether the method is `INSERT` or `SELECT`

***For example,***

Just consider you are get value from URL like `https://somesite.somedomain/databaseoperations.php` and your `databaseoperations.php` has following queries

```
$user_id = $_POST['user_id']; 
$operation = $_POST['operation']; 
require_once('Connect.php'); 

if($operation == "select"){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Loans WHERE user_id=?"; 
....
// Here, perform Select from database using $user_id as a
// bound param, then echo json_encode()
}else if ($operation == "insert"){
 //Just perform Database Insert operation
}else{
 echo json_encode(["error"=>"Illegal Operation"]);
}
```

**In iOS**

Just perform `URLRequest` with `post` parameter with `user_id` and `operation`.

For get Value your post parameters like below,

```
let url = "https://somsite.somedomain/databaseoperations.php"
let postParam = "user_id=4&operation=select"
```

For Put Value `postParam` becomes,

```
let postParam = "user_id=5&operation=insert"
```

**For reference :-**

```
let postParam="user_id=5&operation=insert"
let url = URL(string: "https://somsite.somedomain/databaseoperations.php")
var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
request.httpBody = postParam.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data,response,error in
        guard error == nil else{
            print(error!)
            return
        }

    do{
        let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)
        print(jsonObject)
    }catch{

        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

I hope it'll be give some idea to you.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i'm just wondering where will i exactly put the postParam after i declare the value of it?

Comment: thank you for your answer. i'm just wondering where will i exactly put the postParam after i declare the value of it? Also i have a specific value of the user_id that based on "getUserId.text" on my Swift code is this code possible for your code in postParam: "user_id=\(getUserId.text)&operation=select"

Comment: Your welcome. Yes `user_id=\(getUserId.text!)&operation=select` is right bro.

Comment: i'm just wondering where will i exactly put the postParam after i declare the value of it?

Comment: see updated answer . You can do like this reference code. I will update with specific answer when I am in computer.

Comment: @RAJAMOHAN-S, your `databaseoperations.php` has a SQL injection vulnerability in it. Have you also recommended to the OP how to restrict access to the data, so that someone armed with Curl cannot simply download the whole table? I presume a table called `Loans` contains private data.

Comment: I have made the code more safe, and made mention of bound parameters, so that a beginner does not copy an unsafe example. Please do not get into the habit of thinking that because this is not explicitly a security question, you do not have to teach good security practice. Beginners will copy what you offer, whether it is any good or not.

Comment: @halfer , Okay thank you so much bro. I mind and will keep it :)

Comment: the code i gave above this question is in "func showTable()" and i call it to my override func viewDidLoad() so that i can see the output. However, given to the codes that you have given me, where will i put the "showTable()" ?? I'm sorry for asking too much. i'm just 2 months old for this programming language.